# Django KeyError at /register/

Tags: django

I have a registration that let users register and i'm having difficulty fixing it.

The problem is when a user submits a single field instead of the whole form for example an email . I get this error

```
KeyError at /register/

password
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _get_errors
  115.             self.full_clean()
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  271.         self._clean_form()
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _clean_form
  299.             self.cleaned_data = self.clean()
File "C:\o\17\mysite\pet\forms.py" in clean
  31.       if self.cleaned_data['password'] != self.cleaned_data['password1']:

Exception Type: KeyError at /register/
Exception Value: password
```

I tried to fix this solution using if . If user has a submitted a username or any other required field , process the form otherwise redisplay the original form.

but I still get the same error.

This is my edited views.py ***(at the bottom of the page is my original RegistrationForm)***

```
def PetRegistration(request):   
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:HappyLand'))

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = UserRegistration(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        if username:
            email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            if email:
                password=form.cleaned_data['password']
                if password:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'], 
            email=form.cleaned_data['email'], 
            password=form.cleaned_data['password']
            )
                    user.is_active = True
                    user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
                    user.save()

                    person = authenticate(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'], 
            password=form.cleaned_data['password']
            )

                    Person.objects.create(user_id=user.id, 
                    name=form.cleaned_data['name'],birthday=form.cleaned_data['birthday'])

                    login(request, person)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:HappyLand'))

return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': UserRegistration()})
```

How can I fix this error and also how could I display an error message on the other fields that the user didn't fill out like "Error Missing Field , Please Fill this Field".

```
def PetRegistration(request):   
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:HappyLand'))

if request.method =='POST':
    form = UserRegistration(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'], 
            email=form.cleaned_data['email'], 
            password=form.cleaned_data['password']
            )
        user.is_active = True
        user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        user.save()

        person = authenticate(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'], 
            password=form.cleaned_data['password']
            )

        Person.objects.create(user_id=user.id, 
            name=form.cleaned_data['name'],birthday=form.cleaned_data['birthday'])

        login(request, person)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:HappyLand'))

return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': UserRegistration()})
```

My forms.py

```
class UserRegistration(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    birthday = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1950, 2012)))

    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
        )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=(u'Verify Password'), 
        widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
        )

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "That user is already taken , please select another ")

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password'] != self.cleaned_data['password1']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The password does not match ")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

My models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: I added a `kontext['name']`, bur forgot to add something to it, so I added something `kontext['name'] = 'someName'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is with your `clean()`. In `clean()`, you are trying to access field `password` on form's `cleaned_data`. `password` will only be available on `cleaned_data` if the user has filled this field. So, you must check that `password` is there in `cleaned_data` before trying to access it.

Changing your `clean()`:

```
def clean(self):
    if 'password' in self.cleaned_data and 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and self.cleaned_data['password'] != self.cleaned_data['password1']:
        raise forms.ValidationError("The password does not match ")
    return self.cleaned_data
```

You can provide a keyword argument `error_messages` on form field for showing error message like "Error Missing Field , Please Fill this Field".

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required':'Error Missing Field , Please Fill this Field'})
```

There is a bug in your view.

is_valid() populates errors on the form but this same form instance must be sent to the template so that you can access the errors on the form's fields.

But in your view, you have only one call to `render()` which gets called even in case of an invalid form on a post request. And in this `render()`, you are creating a new instance of form. So, this new form which you are sending to template will not have any errors.

So, making slight modification to your view:

```
def PetRegistration(request):   
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:HappyLand'))

    form = UserRegistration() #This will be used in GET request
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = UserRegistration(request.POST) #This will be used in POST request
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'], 
                email=form.cleaned_data['email'], 
                password=form.cleaned_data['password']
            )
            user.is_active = True
            user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            user.save()

            person = authenticate(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'], 
                password=form.cleaned_data['password']
            )

            Person.objects.create(user_id=user.id, 
                name=form.cleaned_data['name'],birthday=form.cleaned_data['birthday'])

            login(request, person)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:HappyLand'))

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

Notice in your view, I have added `form=UserRegistration()` before checking if its POST request, and have added the comment at two places where we are instantiating `UserRegistration`. And then in `render()`, you should send this `form`.

Then your `{{form.username.errors}}` will work.

Comment: the error message isn't working . {{form.username.errors}}<label for="id_username">Username:</label>{{form.username}}

Comment: Can You help me for a moment . If you see in my forms . A user will get an error if a username is already taken but my form doesn't display that error . How come? {{ form.username.errors }}

Answer (score 1):

I just modified your forms.py

```
class UserRegistration(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    birthday = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1950, 2012)))
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
        )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=(u'Verify Password'), 
        widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
        )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserRegistration, self).clean()
        username = cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        password1 = cleaned_data.get("password1")

        #check if username exist  
        user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if user:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "That user is already taken , please select another ")

        #check password
        if password != password1:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Your current and confirm password do not match.")

        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: after `if form.is_valid()` create `else` then under the else call the `form.errors`

Comment: Okay Cathy , I custom the form from scratch and create else and call form.errors and I still don't know what wrong . I just don't have enough knowledge

Comment: Do you want to me to post my html?

Comment: create a chat room, let's talk there