# django form posting to another form

Tags: html, django, forms, redirect, post

I am trying to create a form that feeds another form. The latest iteration is shown below.  The flow is as follows:

A user selects a semester from both drop down lists on form1.
When that page is POSTed the values from these drop down lists are used as a query filter for the next form that loads.

I have even tried storing this data in sessions but I just can't get anything to work. I have searched for answers but just can't find any.   Most likely this is because I am new to Django and might not understand some of the information that I found.

```
class CopyClassEnrollmentForm1(forms.Form):
    original_semester=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Semester.objects.filter(is_active=True))
    new_semester=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Semester.objects.filter(is_active=True))

class CopyClassEnrollmentForm2(forms.Form):
    original_class = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Schedule.objects.filter(), empty_label=None)
    new_class = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Schedule.objects.filter(), empty_label=None)

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super (CopyClassEnrollmentForm2,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['original_class'].queryset = Schedule.objects.filter(semester=original_semester)

@staff_member_required
def copy_class_enrollment1(request):
    form = CopyClassEnrollmentForm1(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        request.session['original_semester'] = form.cleaned_data['original_semester']
        request.session['new_semester'] = form.cleaned_data['new_semester']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('copy_class_enrollment2'))

    else:
        form = CopyClassEnrollmentForm1()

    return render(request, "school/admin/copy_class_enrollment1.html", { 'form': form,})



def copy_class_enrollment2(request):
    form = CopyClassEnrollmentForm2(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        original_semester = request.session['original_semester']
        new_semester = request.session['new_semester']
        original_semester = form.cleaned_data['original_semester']
        new_semester = form.cleaned_data['new_semester']

    else:
        form = CopyClassEnrollmentForm2()

    return render(request, "school/admin/copy_class_enrollment2.html", { 'form': form,})
```

Comment: OK, that looks good so far (except that you haven't defined `original_semester` in the second form). So where is the copy_class_enrollment2  view? What exactly happens when you use it?

Comment: Added copy_class_enrollment2

Comment: NameError at /school/CopyClassEnrollment2/
global name 'original_semester' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing things in the wrong order in your second view. You need to pass the values from the session into the form, and the form has to take the values from the kwargs:

```
class CopyClassEnrollmentForm2(forms.Form):
    original_class = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Schedule.objects.filter(), empty_label=None)
    new_class = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Schedule.objects.filter(), empty_label=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        original_semester = kwargs.pop('original_semester')
        new_semester = kwargs.pop('new_semester')
        super (CopyClassEnrollmentForm2,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['original_class'].queryset = Schedule.objects.filter(semester=original_semester)

def copy_class_enrollment2(request):
    original_semester = request.session['original_semester']
    new_semester = request.session['new_semester']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CopyClassEnrollmentForm2(request.POST, original_semester=original_semester, new_semester=new_semester)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do something
    else:
        form = CopyClassEnrollmentForm2(original_semester=original_semester, new_semester=new_semester)

    return render(request, "school/admin/copy_class_enrollment2.html", { 'form': form,})
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at this line:   original_semester = kwargs.pop('original_semester').      KeyError at /school/CopyClassEnrollment2/
'original_semester'

Comment: Might be because of the form not being cleaned.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846743/django-keyerror-at-register

Comment: DUH. Never mind. I forgot to add the variables to the CopyClassEnrollmentForm2 after the "else:" statement. You had it in your answer but I failed to place it in my code.   This works.Thank you very much!